# Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in R [error in variables problem]

Tags: r, regression, mle

I am estimating cross-sectional regressions - fragment:

> lm(rate~liqamih.log+cap.log+F1+F2, data=x)

of the R code listed below.

F1 and F2 are the coefficients estimates of time series model.

In such case we need to deal with so called "error in variables problem". In literature (links: gendocs.ru/docs/23/22031/conv_1/file1.pdf‎ (page 1091) and papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=6992 (whole article)) the MLE method is one of the effective solution of this problem.

I would like to implement method introduced by KIM (reference to literature-links above) in my R code below. HOW to IMPLEMENT referenced method into my R code?

```
data<-read.table("reg5-dane.csv", head=T, sep=";", dec=",")
  data$indx <- as.numeric(gl(123*334,334,123*334))
lst1 <- split(data[,-53],data[,53]) #max 53 variables in "lst2" regression
any(sapply(lst1,nrow)!=123)
#[1] FALSE
lst2 <- lapply(lst1[sapply(lst1,function(x) !(all(rowSums(is.na(x))>0)))],
               function(x) summary(lm(rate~liqamih.log+cap.log+F1+F2, data=x)) )
capture.output(lst2,file="nooldor_regr_summ.txt")
# - f2 -f6 /+f2 -f5 +F6 - f6 - f2 - liq + f6 - f6 +f2 - f4 - f4 +f3

capture.output(lst2,file="nooldor_regr_summ.csv")
```

There is 123 time observations on 334 subjects observations. For each of 123 time points I am running one regressions with 334 subjects (so I am repeating it 123 times for each point of time).
I post this topic also in CrossValidated.com - because I need help from one who can have strong background in statistics/econometrics and also in R programming.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Also your code is not reproducible (due to lack of data) and overall pretty badly written. What is this `assign` business in `f4`?

Comment: I left only the core / important part of the code. The problem stays the same.